# make a div fit into whitespace if possible, else grow in size

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

my question is rather complicated.

In my layout i have a left column and a right column. For example 30% and 70% width. below them there is another item, now theres the challenge:

if my 30% column is higher than the 70% column the "challengeblock" should fill on the right side.
if the right side is the higher one the "challengeblock" should be on the bottom with 100% width.

Here I made an example:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/by6tkg7L/
```

The green one should fit on the right in this code.

I tried it with

```
flex-grow
```

in this case, but also had a try with grid (not to experienced there so seems like I need to read some more first)

I´m also open for masonary layouts like with isotope, but found no way so far to make it fill OR make it grow depending on the rest.

I would ofcourse prefer a CSS-only way and would like to avoid calculating with JS.

Tahnks in advance

Comment: Can you post your jsfiddle code into the question. The question needs to be self contained. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Css only solution. Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/by6tkg7L/1/

To be able to see it working you have to change height of the blue block (class **.right_top**).

I only modified the css, i used `block` and `inline-block` on the child elements (with `float: left`) and i've set `flex` only on the *question* element setting a `min-width` and a `max-width` instead of a static `width`.

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.left{
    background-color: red;
    height: 500px;
    width: 30%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
.right_top{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 500px;
    width: 70%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
.question{
    min-width: 70%;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    height: 300px;
    display:flex;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="right_top">
        </div>
    <div class="question">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, that´s exactly what i was looking for